# How to edit products page of wp ecommerce plugin?

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

The one problem that is always finds me again is that I cant find particular pages. Lets say I created a product from the admin panel. I have a link to the page, but now I need to edit the look of that page. Where I can find this page physicaly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress uses a template system- content is stored in a database and gets inserted into a template when a page is served, so pages and products don't exist as separate, physical things.

To edit the templates Wp E-Commerce uses, go to Settings > Store and click on the presentation tab. There will be an advanced Theme Settings box which will allow you to select which templates you want to move into your active theme directory. Once you've moved them you can then edit those templates without losing changes in a plugin update.

Note that, much like WordPress posts and pages, your single product pages all share the same template, so you'll need some additional code in your template to determine what the current product is if you want to style specific products differently than others.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe, you will know this:

I updated my checkout page by updating the file which was in ....wp-ecommerce/wpsc-theme/wpsc-shopping_cart_page.php

It worked fine for a while, but now some of the changed states reverted to the previous state. Actually, I can even delete the file that I mentioned above, so it means wordpress is loading this file from somewhere else. Any ideas from where and what had happened? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user385917 - If you've moved the theme files as I noted above, it's now pulling the theme files from your active theme in the `wp-content/themes/` directory. You shouldn't edit the ones in the plugin's folder, as those will get overwritten if you ever update the plugin.